# How to update a file using a CURSOR in SQLRPGLE

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

Can someone tell me how to update a data using the CURSOR in sqlrpgle.Is there a way updating data just by using  CURSOR rather than using the Update statement in SQLRPGLE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What update statement do you refer to ? UPDATE rpg order or UPDATE SQL ?

With UPDATE SQL :

```
  Exec SQL declare c1 cursor for
     SELECT *
        FROM xxxx ..
     for update ;
```

fetch the records as usual , and before each fetch :

```
 exec sql
      update xxxxx  set FIELD = :FIELDRPG
      where current of c1;
```